# Adding List<T> into a List<T> C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a structure:

```
public class FolderDirectoryStructure
{
    public string ChildFolder {get; set;}
    public FileExtension Extension {get; set;}
}
```

And another structure:

```
public class FileExtension
{
    public string Extension {get; set;}
    public int ExtensionCount {get; set;}
}
```

What I now want to do is add an existing FileExtension to my FolderDirectoryStructure.  So something like:

```
private List<FolderDirectoryStructure> FolderDS = new List<FolderDirectoryStructure>();

private List<FileExtension> extensions = new List<FileExtension>();

extensions.Add(new FileExtension() {Extension = ".jpg", ExtensionCount = 1});

FolderDS.Add(new FolderDirectoryStructure() {ChildFolder =
@"C:\users\blah\desktop\somefolder", Extension = extensions});
```

This doesn't work as I get the error:

> Cannot Implicity Convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'DirectoryStructure.Extensions'

I also tried:

```
FolderDS.Add(new FolderDirectoryStructure() { ChildFolder =
@"C:\users\blah\desktop\somefolder", Extension = new Extensions()
{extensions.Extension, extensions.ExtensionCount} });
```

I was also thinking of an AddRange since I'm trying to add a range of extensions, but that doesn't seem to take.  I just seem to be running out of options.

So hoping someone can help me out with this I would certainly appreciate it.

Comment: The property `Extension` in `FolderDirectoryStructure` should be a `List<FileExtension>`.

Comment: I don't see a `DirectoryStructure.Extensions` type so your error message does not match the code you're posted.

Comment: Sorry @DStanley I was trying to simplify it and got a little tongue tied with the variables.  unlucky was able to weed through it and figure it out for me though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the `Extension` property of `FolderDirectoryStructure` is of type `FileExtension` and you are trying to assign a list of `FileExtension` to this property causing the error. So better you change the property as a list. Then  Your code will works fine is you change the definition of the class like this:

```
public class FolderDirectoryStructure
{
    public string ChildFolder {get; set;}
    public List<FileExtension> Extension {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class FolderDirectoryStructure
{
    public string ChildFolder {get; set;}
    public FileExtension Extension {get; set;}
}
```

Declares Extension to be a `FileExtension`. You tried to *assign* a `List<FileExtension>` to it here:

```
FolderDS.Add(new FolderDirectoryStructure() {ChildFolder =
@"C:\users\blah\desktop\somefolder", Extension = extensions});
```

Clearly that won't work. Fix the discrepancy and the error will go away.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
public FileExtension Extension {get; set;}
```

but you are trying to set the variable

```
extensions
```

which is a

```
List<Extension>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class has 1 extension object but you are trying to set with list of them you should rework your class like this :

```
public class FolderDirectoryStructure
{
    public string ChildFolder {get; set;}
    public List<FileExtension> Extension {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In FolderDirectoryStructure Extension is a single item, you cannot assign a List to the FileExtension property, the error is saying exactly what is wrong. This WOULD work

```
public class FolderDirectoryStructure
{
    public string ChildFolder {get; set;}
    public List<FileExtension> Extension {get; set;}//change this
}
```